# Selecting and Deselecting the value in text box on Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selection

Hi Friends i have multiple text box in my form there i didn't done any code in on click for deselecting, the thing is that  some how chrome fulfill my need (**in Chrome when i click again on same selected text box the Cursor is placed exactly where i clicked again**) but when moving to other browser it's not happening(in **IE and FireFox able to select and not able to deselecting**). Any one who gone through this, suggest me some code to do deselecting.

Plz help me with this,

Here is my code and **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/billajo21/3zmdmxgm/)**

HTML

```
<input Value="sdfsdfsdf">
<input Value="8545555">
<input Value="Billa">
```

JQ

```
$(document).on("click", "input:text", null, function (ev) {
    alert("hi");
    $(this).select();
    return this;
});
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: I didn't saw any problem in Firefox v31. On which version you are testing.

Comment: Firefox v31 only actually i need the code to do deselec the already selected text box also Cursor need to be in placed exactly where i clicked again. can u help me with this

Comment: This is funny, my firefox just got updated to v32. And now it's not even deselecting the selected text on click.

Comment: @SandeshDamkondwar Dude i know why it happen, actually i didn't done any code in on click for deselecting, the real fun is some how chrome fulfill my need but when moving to other browser it's not happening. Any one who gone through this suggest me some code to do deselection.

Comment: Check the documentation for `.select()` at http://api.jquery.com/select/

It says 

> The method for retrieving the current selected text differs from one browser to another. A number of jQuery plug-ins offer cross-platform solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead off `on click` event try with `on focus`:

```
$(document).on("focus", "input:text", null, function (ev) {
    $(this).select();
});
```

Comment: thanks dude, but i already tried  on focus it is working only with **fireFox Not In Chrome And IE **

Comment: Who cares about old IE users, only chinese peoples are outdated to older IE. If it's working in IE>9, then I would have gone for that.

Comment: ya dude i am using IE9> only @Sandesh Damkondwar

Answer (score 0):

**Try this-**

```
var selected = false;
$(document).on("click", "input:text", null, function (ev) {
    if (!selected) {
        $(this).select();
        selected = true;
    } else {
        selected = false;
        this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd;//clearing the selection        
    }    
    return this;
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/3zmdmxgm/13/)

### UPDATE-

**If you want the cursor position unchanged after selection & deselection**

```
$("input:text").data("selectionStart", 0);
$("input:text").data("selected", false);

$(document).on("select", "input:text", null, function (ev) {
    if (this.selectionStart === this.selectionEnd) {
        $(this).data("selectionStart", this.selectionStart);
    }
});
$(document).on("click", "input:text", null, function (ev) {
    if ($(this).data("selected")==false) {
        $(this).select();
        $(this).data("selected", true);
    } else {
        this.selectionEnd = this.selectionStart = $(this).data("selectionStart");
        $(this).data("selected", false);
    }
    return this;
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/3zmdmxgm/18/)

Comment: still small prob in Chrome ( that cursor is going to the end on deselecting but worke's good in FireFox And IE) that i will try fix and get back to u

Comment: Your welcome :).Where you want the cursor position on deselection??

Comment: dude i need  Cursor to be placed exactly where i clicked again